# What is scary about William Colt in this scene from Carter & Lovecraft?

Tags: carter-and-lovecraft

This is a question about Jonathan L. Howard's novel Carter & Lovecraft. Listening to it again (in audio-book format), there's a scene where I just don't get what's happening.

In Chapter 15, A Reminiscence of Bertrand Russell, antagonist William Colt visits the main characters' book store. At this point, only Carter knows him (as far as the reader knows) and he stays out of sight of Colt. So that Lovecraft is the only one who interacts with Colt. The reader doesn't get much details about her reactions. While Colt appears creepy and weird, he makes no overt threats, doesn't mention directly occult stuff beyond gushing about Russell's work and appears to be just a nerd who loves to flaunt his knowledge and is looking for specialized books.

But by the end, Lovecraft seems utterly terrified of him. More than this, she seems to distrust Carter at this point. And I don't get it! I know that elements of existential horror can be hard to correctly communicate to the reader. I know that the occult and weird science are a traditional horror element in H.P.Lovecraft-inspired story. But this is not something that Howard appears to use that much in his first two novels, at least not in the same way that this scene is portrayed.

Seeing how the chapter's title focuses on him, I've looked a bit at Russell's work. But where I expected some kind of occult, weirder or misanthropic connection, the man appears to have been a mathematician with lots of work in set theory and similar topics. Even considering that this is a story, adding an extra aura of mystic to Russell and considering that the quote fits Colt's character. This just doesn't makes sense unless Lovecraft already knows about Colt. Which she doesn't.

Considering that I don't think there is any explanation about this scene later in the book, **Why is Lovecraft so afraid of Colt in this scene?**

*As a sidenote, my rep is too low to create a tag and I needed to add one. Since I couldn't find one that seemed to fit either the question or the story's title, I put the closest I found.*

Comment: Not sure if it helps but Bertrand Russel proved that the set of all sets, that is a set containing all possible sets (somehow "the Universe" for mathematicians) cannot exist. Roughly, at that time, a set was defined as "an abstract collection of mathematical objects" so, surely, most mathematicians believe that a set of all sets should exist. Russel's argument was a vertiginous and mind-blowing step in the understanding of logic, axioms (and set theory). In addition, Russell was a philosopher, mostly dealing with religion, belief, and work.

Comment: I've created the tag for you. To date there seem to be two stories to this series. I suggest using just the series name (also the name of the first book) for all the stories. Given it was optioned by Warner Bros TV the tags might get convoluted if a series is made.

Comment: @Edlothiad Thanks for the tag. The one you added was what I expected. I expected there to be one along the lines of  "scene explanation", I don't know I missed it.

Comment: @Taladris the way you word it makes even more sense in the context of the story at least. I'll listen to it to see if that brings out more.

Comment: Taladris, that makes a lot of sense in context; Russel's proof of the nonexistence of "The Set Of All Sets" undermine dteh orderly structure of mathematics. In it's turn, the Cthulhu Mythos shows that the orderly universe is itself undermined by the actions and or potential actions of the Old Ones and suchlike. Someone spouting how they are a huge fan of that principle of Russel's and having occult power at the *same* time? That would be like a person talking casually about how they admire David Benetar and idly playing with a vial of 100% lethality modified Smallpox virus - a *veiled threat*